Conditions for the noexcept expression
Please tell me if I defined the conditions for noexcept expressions correctly in this cases?
class scheme_host_port
    {
    public:
        using value_type = std::string;

        scheme_host_port() = delete;
        scheme_host_port(value_type const &value) noexcept(std::is_nothrow_copy_constructible_v<value_type>) : value_{value} {};
        scheme_host_port(value_type &&value) noexcept(std::is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<value_type>) : value_{value} {};

        scheme_host_port(scheme_host_port const &) = delete;            
        scheme_host_port &operator=(scheme_host_port const &) = delete;

        scheme_host_port(scheme_host_port &&) noexcept(std::is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<value_type>) = default;
        scheme_host_port &operator=(scheme_host_port &&) noexcept(std::is_nothrow_move_assignable_v<value_type>) = default;
        value_type operator()() const { return value_; }                                                                    
        bool operator==(scheme_host_port const &rhs) const noexcept { return this->value_ == rhs.value_; }
        bool operator!=(scheme_host_port const &rhs) const noexcept { return !(this->value_ == rhs.value_); }

    private:
        value_type value_;
    };


The scheme_host_port move constructor is initializing its value_ using value_type's copy constructor.  So that one is incorrect.  I think the expression to the noexcept should not need to use type traits.  q.v. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept

Also, you forgot to specify noexcept for the conversion operator.

@Eljay The scheme_host_port move constructor is initializing its value_ using value_type's copy constructor That looks like a bug to me

@digito_evo Well spotted, but I would just call it get_value

@catnip Maybe. Although the OP might have specific use cases for the conversation operator.
